# WinDef.h why are far and near still here? C++

Tags: winapi

I was going through some code when I stumbled upon the `far` qualifier for the first time, now it makes sense to me why these used to be used. But with the memory model we use today why are these even in place anymore? Do people actually use these in practice, or are they just there as a trinket from the past?

What would even be the difference between using `typedef BOOL near *PBOOL;` and `typedef BOOL far *LPBOOL;`?

Is there any ***real*** use for these still? Or should I just look the other way.

```
// WinDef.h ~Line 144
#undef FAR
#undef  NEAR
#define FAR                 far
#define NEAR                near
#ifndef CONST
#define CONST               const
#endif

typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
typedef int                 BOOL;
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
typedef unsigned short      WORD;
typedef float               FLOAT;
typedef FLOAT               *PFLOAT;
typedef BOOL near           *PBOOL;
typedef BOOL far            *LPBOOL;
typedef BYTE near           *PBYTE;
typedef BYTE far            *LPBYTE;
typedef int near            *PINT;
typedef int far             *LPINT;
typedef WORD near           *PWORD;
typedef WORD far            *LPWORD;
typedef long far            *LPLONG;
typedef DWORD near          *PDWORD;
typedef DWORD far           *LPDWORD;
typedef void far            *LPVOID;
typedef CONST void far      *LPCVOID;
```

EDIT: The first comment makes a good point too, what does this mean now if `far` and `near` are defined to nothing?

```
// WinDef.h: Lines 91-91
#define far
#define near
```

Comment: Don't lines 91-2 (in v7.1a at least) also `#define far` and `near` to nothing? But you're right, I doubt they're needed any more.

Comment: There's a lot of really old code out there.

Comment: No reason to use them, they remain for backward compatibility with old code.

Comment: But if they are defined to nothing, how can it support anything? Does it just mean that if the qualifier `near` or `far` is encountered basically treat it as whitespace?

Comment: Defining them to nothing simply avoids compile errors from old code that still contains those qualifiers.  They definitely can and should be treated as whitespace in modern code (modern being anything written in the last 20 years or so).

Comment: @BumSkeeter, since they are #define to nothing, it just means that currently `LPWORD` and `PWORD` are the exact same types.

Comment: Compiling 20 year old code sans modification is a misnomer. Usually anything over 10 years old will have some sort of compiler incompatibility... strings unsafe, crt depricated, use posix name, directx, ect. When recompiling something with the words near and far as a modifier to a pointer chances are you can put up with the error that would be generated if near and far are taken as normal words. Compare that to mysterious errors a newbie gets if they use near or far as a parameter name in a function. Windows being able to run old apps was vital, not so sure about compiling old code.

Answer (score 18):

Microsoft carries a great burden, they do everything possible to make programs that were written 35 years ago still compile and run on modern Windows versions.  No sane company would ever try to so something as silly as that, it is however the core reason that they were successful.  Once a declaration makes it into a Windows SDK header, it takes a very, very good reason to get it removed again.

And yes, that really does mean that some ancient 16-bit C program somewhere can still be maintained and re-compiled.  Which uses near and far pointers, that was necessary back then.  That it still works on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows after being recompiled is no accident.

This kind of back-compat exists in a language like C as well.  To this day, a string literal is not a `const char*`, just `char*`.  Makes no sense whatsoever but fixing it would break *way* too many existing programs.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, they are not currently used for anything.

1. Its not worth the effort to manually remove them (especially when
   the compiler can do it for you).
2. Keep in mind that Windows supports
   multiple architectures, and it would suck to have to go add them
   back in if it were ported to an architecture where they made sense
   again.

Comment: After 20 years of writing code where NEAR==FAR==nothing, I doubt there are a lot of code that would work in such architecture, should that madness ever come back.

Comment: @rodrigo: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @SigTerm a bit late to the party, but I want to disagree and counter with the boy scout rule. Things like this make it hard to support legacy code. I would remove the far/near and see if it compiles for the target architecture and unit tests still run.